# Excel file is not working in cron job

Tags: php, cron

I am generating and sending Excel file in Email using cron job. When I hit run the script manually it works fine , Email is receiving with correct excel. But when email is receiving by the cron the Excel file is not correct. Any idea about this issue ?

Comment: what will difference between those two xls file? which one you run manually and one you run by cron job

Comment: could you tell me more about this problem. like what you want to do? I want to know some example like code.

Comment: Same code is running, Means When I hit the URL it works fine . and the same URL I set in cron job . when cron job runs the xls file is not opening.

Comment: Don't know what logic are you using. you can follow these steps to achieve this goal. 
Step 1- generate xls. 
Step 2- save xls file in folder . 
Step 3- get xls file url and attached it in email. 

Hope it will help thought.